# Release the memory of threading.Timer in Python

Tags: python, multithreading, timer

I'm doing a packet injection with `scapy` and creating a `threading.Timer` which deletes the packet information from the dictionary after 10 seconds.
If I receive a response before 10 seconds, I'm cancelling the `Timer` and deleting the packet information from the dictionary. Since I'm cancelling the Timer, I can put `.join()` here. But when the Timer expires, there's no mechanism to `.join()`.

When I run the program, the memory keeps on increasing. No doubt, increasing is slow (Initially 2% in a 1 GB RAM system. In 20 minutes, it went to 3.9%). But still it keeps on increasing. I tried `gc.collect()`. But it's of no help. I'm monitoring the memory with `top`.

Below is the code. Sorry for the large code. I guess it's better to give the whole code to know if somewhere I'm missing something.

```
from threading import Timer
from scapy.all import *
import gc

class ProcessPacket():
    #To write the packets to the response.pcap file    
    def pcapWrite(self, pkts):
        writerResponse(pkts)
        writerResponse.flush()
        return

    #cancels the Timer upon receiving a response
    def timerCancel(self, ipPort):
        if self.pktInfo[ipPort]["timer"].isAlive():
            self.pktInfo[ipPort]["timer"].cancel()
            self.pktInfo[ipPort]["timer"].join()  
        self.delete(ipPort)
        return

    #deletes the packet information from pktInfo
    def delete(self, ipPort):
        if self.pktInfo.has_key(ipPort):
            self.pcapWrite(self.pktInfo[ipPort]["packets"])
            del self.pktInfo[ipPort]
        return

    #processes the received packet and sends the response
    def createSend(self, pkt, ipPort):
        self.pktInfo[ipPort]["packets"] = [pkt]
        self.pktInfo[ipPort]["timer"] = Timer(10, self.delete, args=[ipPort])        
        myPkt = IP(src = pkt[IP].dst, dst = pkt[IP].src)/ TCP(dport = pkt[TCP].sport, sport = pkt[TCP].dport, flags = 'SA')
        self.pktInfo[ipPort]["packets"].append(myPkt)        
        send(myPkt, verbose=0)
        self.pktInfo[ipPort]["timer"].start()
        return

    #constructor
    def __init__(self):
        self.count = 0
        self.writerResponse=PcapWriter('response.pcap',append = True)
        self.pktInfo = {}
        return

    #from sniff
    def pktCallback(self,pkt):    
        ipPort = pkt[IP].src + str(pkt[TCP].sport) + pkt[IP].dst + str(pkt[TCP].dport)
        flag=pkt.sprintf('%TCP.flags%')
        if self.count == 10:
            self.count = 0
            gc.collect()
        if not self.pktInfo.has_key(ipPort) and flag == 'S':
            self.pktInfo[ipPort] = {}
            self.createSend(pkt, ipPort)
            self.count += 1
        elif self.pktInfo.has_key(ipPort):
            self.timerCancel(ipPort)
            self.count += 1
        return

#custom filter for sniff
def myFilter(pkt):
    if pkt.haslayer(IP):
        if pkt[IP].src == "172.16.0.1":
            return 1
        return 0                

if __name__ == '__main__':      
    respondObj = ProcessPacket()
    sniff(iface = 'eth0', filter = "tcp", prn = respondObj.pktCallback, lfilter = myFilter)
```

In the program, I don't see any other memory consuming factor other than `pktInfo` and the `Timer`. `pktInfo` is increasing and decreasing so the problem is with `Timer`. How can I free memory of the expired or cancelled Timers?

**EDIT 1:**
I modified the `delete()` function:

```
#deletes the packet information from pktInfo
def delete(self, ipPort):
    if self.pktInfo.has_key(ipPort):
        print "Before", len(self.pktinfo.keys()), sys.getsizeof(self.pktinfo)
        self.pcapWrite(self.pktInfo[ipPort]["packets"])
        self.pktInfo[ipPort]["timer"]=None
        self.pktInfo[ipPort]=None
        del self.pktInfo[ipPort]
        gc.collect()
        print "After", len(self.pktinfo.keys()), sys.getsizeof(self.pktinfo)
    return
```

After deletion the number of elements in `self.pktinfo` decreases. The size of the `self.pktinfo` remains same for a long time but eventually changes (decreases or increases). But the memory of system doesn't seem to be released. `top` shows the same behaviour that the memory used by the program is continuously increasing.

Answer (score 0):

Release all references to unneeded Timer objects. (e.g. `self.pktInfo[ipPort]["timer"] = None`) - if you don't the garbage collector won't free up anything.

Comment: Tried. Doesn't seem to effect. Please refer to the Edit section of the question.

Comment: any differences in the a-bit-longer time running behaviour, e.g. after 30min/after 1h?

Comment: i'm running the code for around 8-9 hours. Couldn't find any difference. Or the difference is negligible. Is it possible for `top` to show the incorrect value or is there any kind of cache memory not being released to the OS?

Comment: does it keep increasing? if yes, there should be a resource leak somewhere (perhaps not in your code, but in a library?)

Comment: It kept on increasing and ran up to 13 hours fine. By that time it has used 71% of memory. Till than it kept on increasing. After that the system got slowed down and the memory usage kept on fluctuating around 64%~72%.

Comment: top can show different memory usages. By now I'm pretty sure the consumption has nothing to do with `threading.Timer` (your original question). My next test would be to test parallel with a big memory consumer. If the code then consumes the same absolute amount of memory per time, consumption is directly related to it. If not (both consumers together use up less than each individually) your system might just use that memory for buffers.

Comment: what do you mean by Big memory consumer?

Comment: anything that hogs loads of memory. just to look whether your process uses the same or less memory _as reported by top_ compared to alone