# How to pause and resume Python threading.Timer

Tags: python, multithreading, timer

In python, `threading.Timer` works fine to execute a function after sometime. But there is no pause or resume feature. Is there any other way to do it?

Something like this is required.

```
from threading import Timer
from time import sleep
def Hello():
    print "hello"
t=Timer(10, Hello)
t.start()
sleep(3)
### <Pause Timer t>
### <do some work>
### <Resume Timer t>
```

It would also be helpful if it is known for how much time the Timer has started or how much time is left. So the above can be done something like this:

```
### x =  Time passed by Timer t
### t.cancel()
### <do some work>
### t=Timer(10-x, Hello)
### t.start()
```

**Edit 1:**

This is my code after the answer by vitaut:

```
## My Timer Class ##

from threading import Timer as threadTimer
from time import time, sleep
from random import randint as rint

class MyTimer:

    def __init__(self, key, delete):
        self.startTime = time()
        self.timer = threadTimer(15, delete, args=[key])
        self.timer.start()
    def pause(self):
        self.timer.cancel()
        self.endTime = time()
    def resume(self, delete, key):
        self.timer = threadTimer(15-(self.endTime-self.startTime), delete, args=[key])
        self.timer.start()
    def cancel(self):
        self.timer.cancel()
```

I'm using this code for testing:

```
class MyClass:

    def __init__(self):
        self.dict={}

    def delete(self, key):
        print key, time()-self.dict[key]["stime"]
        self.dict[key]["timer"]=None
        self.dict[key]=None
        del self.dict[key]

    def doSomeWork(self, key):
        for i in xrange(10):
            x=str(rint(0,3))
            if self.dict.has_key(key):
                self.dict[key]["timer"].pause()
                print key,
                sleep(1)
                self.dict[key]["timer"].resume(self.delete, key)
        print

    def createDict(self):
        print "Pausing Timer for 1 second for ",
        for i in xrange(10):
            self.dict[i]={}
            self.dict[i]["timer"]=MyTimer(key, self.delete)
            self.dict[i]["stime"]=time()

x=MyClass()
x.createDict()
x.doSomeWork()
```

The Output:

```
Pausing Timer for 1 second for  0 1 0 2 1 0 2 1 1 0
3 15.0000641346
4 15.0000319481
5 15.0000360012
6 15.0000460148
7 15.0002529621
8 15.0000050068
9 15.0001029968
0 16.000754118
2 16.0007479191
1 16.0011930466
```

Since it's pausing the Timer with key 1 for 4 times each for 1 seconds. So the final time for 1 should be 19+ seconds (Expected). But it's showing 16 only.

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK the `Timer` class doesn't have pause/resume functionality but you can easily simulate it with `start`/`cancel` and keeping track of the time when the timer was started yourself.

Comment: It's easy if there's a single Timer running. But when there are numbers of them like in this question, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29918905/release-the-memory-of-threading-timer-in-python, Keeping track of each and every Timer is kinda difficult.

Comment: Well, you can define your own class on top of `Timer` and use it in multiple places.

Comment: Idea is nice. Why it didn't came to my mind. Thanks. lemme try and get back to u.

Comment: Added the code. Please check once. It has some bug which I'm unable to find.